# How do I go further back in time with git rebase -i

Tags: git, rebase

I'm trying to delete a single git commit from history.  It introduced a file with a filename that can't be used on chromebooks, and is making it impossible for someone with a chromebook to pull any updates.

From what I've read online, I'm supposed to use `git rebase -i` then delete the line that has the commit that introduced the file.

Unfortunately, this interactive rebase only shows the ~10 most recent commits.  I need to go further back in time.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would say `git rebase -i <sha-of-commit>~1`. But don't. Use `git filter-repo` and delete just the file from the history.